# Created Table with new Column but needs to replaced by Old column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Created a Table with `ModifiedItems` as a **New Column** which has same kind of data as the `Items` column of the *same table*

Old table is like this

```
ID                      Items                     name
1                        -- Data --                 Some Name  
2                        -- Data --                 Some Name  
3                        -- Data --                 Some Name  
4                        -- Data --                 Some Name
```

new table

```
ID                      Items                     name                  newitems
    1                        -- Data --             Some Name         --data--
    2                        -- Data --             Some Name         --data--  
    3                        -- Data --             Some Name         --data--  
    4                        -- Data --             Some Name         --data--
```

`newitems` column is dynamically crated through query to remove some items from the `items` column, now *how i can remove the items column and rename the `newitems` column to items column and commit it permanent so change stays there,*

i do want to use `update` as it is handling my records because of too much of data

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the 'Items' column:

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> DROP COLUMN Items
```

To rename:

```
EXEC sp_rename '<schema>.<table>.newitems', 'Items', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: should i include this at the end of my processing of the query

Comment: Once you have your data in the new column you can run the above.

Comment: run the spx u created

Comment: i am getting this error: `Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 238
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 238
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.`

Comment: whati did is this: `BEGIN 
  ALTER TABLE AccountsDisplayItems_copy DROP COLUMN DisplayItemList;

 /*Faulty Rename*/  
  EXEC sys.sp_rename
  'dbo.AccountsDisplayItems_copy.[NewItems]',
  '[NewItems]',
  'COLUMN'

/*Fixed Rename*/  
EXEC sys.sp_rename
  'dbo.AccountsDisplayItems_copy.[[NewItems]]]',
  'DisplayItemList',
  'COLUMN'
END`

Comment: Are you sure the column 'NewItems' exists on your table 'AccountsDisplayItems_copy'?

Comment: I just verified that this works. Without seeing your exact schema I'm at a loss for what is wrong.